# Wordpress post background by category

Tags: wordpress

I run wordpress website and have custom background skin. For some category's i  need custom skin so i use this category-id and add this code:

```html
.skin{
display:none;
}
```

and after that add my

```html
<div class="custom-category-skin"><img src=""></div>
```

all that works perfect. Now i need the posts in category with custom skin load the skin from the category.How can i do something like that?

Comment: fetch post by using taxonomy. check if category is available then add .skin class otherwise remove class

Comment: This don't help. Some more specific and clean solution please

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: i have this code in my header : <div class="skin">
<img src="">
</div>. and in specific category i have display: none for .skin and add some class="custom-skin" with new div.